# Failing to get simple SoundCloud javascript api method to work

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I have the following code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "f520d2d8f80c87079a0dc7d90db9afa9"
  });

SC.get("/users/3207",{}, function(user){
    console.log("in the function w/ " + user);
});

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The code should print the user name to the console however whenever I run this, my console gives the error of :

**Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server:**
file://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207?client_id=f520d2d8f80c87079a0dc7d90db9afa9&format=json&_status_code_map%5B302%5D=200

However if I were to directly http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207.json?client_id=f520d2d8f80c87079a0dc7d90db9afa9, then I get a valid JSON result.

Is there something incorrect with my how I am using the SC.get function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should test your `index.html` locally on a web-server like Apache and not by opening it as a file.

**Working example**

```js
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "f520d2d8f80c87079a0dc7d90db9afa9"
});

SC.get("/users/3207", {}, function(user) {
  console.log("in the function w/ " + JSON.stringify(user));
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  res.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(user);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Why can not I test it just by opening the index file? I ran the file and res.innerHTML became null.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to keep it short. You are opening your HTML as a local file, that's why you have a path to your index.html file in your browser address (**file://pathtoyourfile**). The external library performs an AJAX request, which only supports following protocol schemes: **http**, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. When you open your file locally, there is no protocol, you MUST run it on a web-server like Apache. If you are new to those things, I recommend you to install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).